# Wordpress - SSL not working - browser console error "Mixed Content" and "Failed to load resource"

Tags: ssl

I wanted to run SSL on my website (tomcar24.pl) but I can't probably due to console error:

http://prntscr.com/qc74tr
http://prntscr.com/qc755u

I tried to find that old domain geriamedica.pl (I used it while developing website) but can't at all. I have downloaded all possible folders - theme and plugins - didn't find anything. Changed theme to default and errors was gone so problem is probably somewhere in theme. Also checked file generating error in wp-includes but there's no such domain. What else could I do? That error appears only on homepage - subpages and wpadmin are totally fine and working.

What should I do and check now?

Comment: Deactivate all of your plugins, see if the problem is resolved. If so, re-activate them one by one, and test each time, until you find out which plugin it is. If that doesn't find it, switch to a default theme (i.e. Twenty Twenty) and test.

Comment: the browser console screenshot you posted specified the exact theme image file that is giving the mixed content message. you can find the reference to it in your theme and change it to https, or you can try using a plugin to auto-fix mixed content for you such as Really Simple SSL